# Glide placeholder image same size as image view

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-glide

i have a placeholder set up for my image view. For some reason, the place holder image does not scale to the size of the image view but when the actual image is uploaded it goes to normal size. How do i make the place holder image the same size as the image view

[image]

[image]

code:

```
        mUsersDB.get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                    if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {

                        String name = documentSnapshot.getString(KEY_NAME);

                        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
                        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
                        TextView navUsername = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.menu_userName);
                        navUsername.setText(name);

                        String image = documentSnapshot.getString(KEY_IMAGE);

                        RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
                                .placeholder(R.drawable.new_post_default_photo)
                                .error(R.drawable.default_static_picture_post)
                                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                                .priority(Priority.HIGH);


                        ImageView navImage = headerView.findViewById(R.id.menu_image);
                        Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                                .load(image)
                                .apply(options.fitCenter())
                                .into(navImage);
```